# Why are reported TTFB results nearly twice the time of reality

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Google Pagespeed insights reports "Reduce server response times (TTFB) -estimated saving 1.72 s" where as Google Chrome Console/network shows 400ms ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference could be explained by the latency (distance) of your 1) client 2)dns server and 3) your backend server, and between the 1) pagespeed server 2) dns and 3) your backend server (possible solution is a cdn setup for your dns and backend server). Your browser has also cached your dns lookup. Flush your dns on your browser to get a better comparison.